# Why are callbacks not firing immediately on losing connection?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, meteor, tcp

I have an ethernet wire hooked into a hardware controller. I am able to connect to it easily. However, I am trying to update a collection when it's disconnected. Here is some sample code.

```
Galil.connections = new Mongo.Collection('_connections');
Galil._createConnection = function (name) {
  check(name, String);

  Galil.connections.upsert(
    { name: name },
    { $setOnInsert: { data: [], connected: false } }
  );

  let socket = net.connect(this.config.connection, Meteor.bindEnvironment(() => {
    Galil.connections.update({ name: name }, { $set: { connected: true } })
  }));
  socket._name = name;

  let setConnectionClosed = Meteor.bindEnvironment(function () {
    Galil.connections.update({ name: name }, { $set: { connected: false } });
  })
  socket.on('close', setConnectionClosed);
  socket.on('end', setConnectionClosed);
  socket.on('error', setConnectionClosed);
}
Galil._commands = Galil._createConnection('commands');
```

I expect that when I unplug the ethernet cable, it should update the connected status to `false`. However, if this *does* happen, it seems to take a considerable amount of time (a few minutes). On the other hand, the `connect` callback seems to work fine

Is there a way to fire a callback to set the connection status as soon as connection is lost?

Comment: i'm too trying to establish the connection with TCP server (with Hardware) but when i unplug the ethernet cable,the events are not fired :(

Comment: interesting question. Maybe, there is some sessionTimeout triggered as the server does not know that the client has lost connection.